# Code to return whether year is leap year or not

Tags: python, function, return, leap-year

I am new to python. i am writing a program that should take an year as input and return a boolean whether the year is a leap year or not. the code i have written does not return anything. where is my mistake?:

```
def leap_y(year):
    leap = False
    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 == 0):
        leap = True
    return leap

year = int(input())
```

Comment: In this example, you're not calling `leap_y()` at all. You're just getting a year. If this is not the full code, can you post the rest?

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? How did you check that your code does anything without using a debugger or printing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should actually "call" the function. Instead of:

```
year = int(input())
```

You must write:

```
year = leap_y(input())
```